# ASP.NET Boilerplate + SignalR

Tags: .net-core, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I'm working on an ASP.NET Boilerplate project. I want to integrate and work with SignalR.

I want to send a notification to all the logged-in users, when a product name is changed by the admin. Can someone provide a good reference to achieve this task?

I use .NET Core 1.0 and Angular 2.

Comment: .NET Core. Angular 4 for front end.

Answer (score 2):

## .NET Core 1.x

Quoting [a member of the SignalR team](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1258#issuecomment-354828963):

> The `0.2.0` version ... was a prototype exploration that was discarded prior to the .NET Core 1.0 release. It will not be updated in the future. The `1.0.0` version (currently in Alpha) is the only supported version of SignalR on ASP.NET Core.
>
> You can try preview builds...

The `1.0.0` version is for .NET Core 2.0.

## .NET Core 2.0

You can now [download](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) `v3.4.1` of the template with the [Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR) preview.

Read the documentation for [SignalR AspNetCore Integration](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration).

Comment: This was really helpful. My project has been developed on ASP.NET core 1.1.0. Seems like I will not be able to integrate SignalR to this project.